# Chrome missing volume slider?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, gui, user-interface

With the new version of Chrome (Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)), I'm missing the volume slider and can only mute the sound from the default media player, but not adjust the volume.

I get the strange suspicion that this is some kind of intentional anti-design pattern because they didn't consider *desktop users might really like this feature and use it every time*.

Is there a way I can get my volume slider back? Or am I stuck having to change my device's volume control every time a video is quieter/louder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to JohnSilver at [Google Chrome Help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hsVkqvOrXMg), there is a flag that when disabled brings back the full media controls. Follow these steps :

- Open a new tab
- Type in :

  ```
   chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls
  ```

[image: New Media Controls]

- Set it to **`Disabled`**
- & You're done.  This is only a temporary solution since eventually the new options will be forced enabled.

Comment: Is this a permanent solution or will this flag be removed like they did with the bookmarks manager's user interface?

Comment: As of v68.0.3440.106 or maybe even earlier, this flag has had intermittent results on some pages. Sometimes for seemingly no reason at all, the volume slider is hidden. A particular .webm served straight from a particular webserver has no volume slider. The same webm served from disk does.

Time to start looking for another browser.

Comment: Maybe worth looking into https://brave.com/

Comment: Except that Brave [uses the exact same media controls as Chrome does](https://community.brave.com/t/braves-new-media-controls-are-lacking/28487) (and also updated them like Chrome) at the cost of at least one [physically disabled person](https://community.brave.com/t/a-general-volume-controller/18274). There's no getting away from this it seems!

Answer (score 2):

This flag will be removed soon and the new design will be permanent. You have to send feedback. On Chrome, click menu icon and go to Help > Report an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling

```
chrome://flags/#global-media-controls-cast-start-stop
```

helped in my case.